# How to change note values in Logic Pro score editor

Tags: macos, logic

When I'm working in the score editor, how can I increase and decrease the duration of the currently selected note?

I.e. from semibreve > minim > crotchet > quaver, and back the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Logic Pro > Window > Open Event List (Cmd 7)

In the event list you will see all the notes and more. Each written note is allocated a length a fraction shorter than the written note. Change the length of one or more notes (all the notes you have selected). Set up a test score, place one note and play with that to get used to how control note lengths, placement and more.

If you have recorded the score by playing a MIDI instrument, the placement and lengths of notes are exactly as you played them, which does not look as tidy in the event list, although you can quantise them if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

With the note selected in the score editor, open the inspector and you should see an "Event" tab.

In the event tab there is a "Length" parameter that you can edit.

The "Length" value is a space separated list of numbers for "bars", "beats, "ticks"

You can also see the "Length" value in the event float [Window->show Event Float]

You can either edit the values directly or click hold and drag up or down on either of the components.